Can't update properties in Ansible role for Prometheus
I am trying to use Prometheus Role: https://github.com/prometheus-community/ansible
I created a playbook - playbook.yaml, with the following content:
---
- hosts: prometheus-server
  become: true
  roles:
    - role: prometheus.prometheus.prometheus
      prometheus_version: "2.43.0"  
      prometheus_config_dir: "/sites/prometheus"
      prometheus_web_listen_address: "0.0.0.0:9090"  
      prometheus_global: {"evaluation_interval": "1m5s", "scrape_interval": "1m", "scrape_timeout": "59s"}
      prometheus_external_labels: {"environment": "env1"}
      prometheus_alert_rules_files: ["/sites/prometheus/rules.d/rules.yml"]
      prometheus_alertmanager_config: 
        - scheme: http
          static_configs:
          - targets:
            - alertmanager-1.xxx:9093
            

The inventory is OK:
all:
  hosts:
    prometheus-server:
      ansible_host: x.x.x.x  
  vars:
    ansible_user: ubuntu
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/id_rsa_test
    ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa myuser@server.x"'

I changed all these values to use rules.d:
In roles/prometheus/templates/prometheus.yml.j2:
{% if not prometheus_agent_mode and prometheus_alert_rules_files != [] %}
rule_files:
  - {{ prometheus_config_dir }}/rules.d/*.rules
{% endif %}

In roles/prometheus/tasks/configure.yml
src: "{{ item }}"
dest: "{{ prometheus_config_dir }}/rules.d/"
owner: root

In ansible/roles/prometheus/meta/argument_specs.yml, nothing to change:
  prometheus_alert_rules:
    description:
      - "Full list of alerting rules which will be copied to C({{ prometheus_config_dir }}/rules.d/ansible_managed.rules)."
      - "Alerting rules can be also provided by other files located in C({{ prometheus_config_dir }}/rules.d/) which have C(*.rules) extension"
      - "Please see default values in role defaults/main.yml"
    type: "list"
    elements: "dict"

When running the playbook, it still returns the default route (even if changed and saved).
I also tried manually adding other tasks, that are not being executed, in tasks:
https://github.com/prometheus-community/ansible/tree/9fd1b0f52954b3f6e1338ef1466a0cb8fd30fd9f/roles/prometheus/tasks
But nothing...
In my server, I manually changed the value and restarted prometheus, to run the playbook and check that it changes again to the "rules" route (to see that the playbook works).
Not sure what I can do...
To help with troubleshooting:

Permissions in the destination server are the same.
I even created some tasks that are not being executed in the role.
SCP WARNINGS are triggered in the playbook (I think that is not related to the problem).

Some of the warnings I receive:
Adding WARNINGS:

[WARNING]: sftp transfer mechanism failed on [X.X.X.X]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
[WARNING]: scp transfer mechanism failed on [X.X.X.X]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information


Adding WARNINGS:
[WARNING]: sftp transfer mechanism failed on [X.X.X.X]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
[WARNING]: scp transfer mechanism failed on [X.X.X.X]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information

Your files in roles/prometheus are going to be ignore at best; confusing Ansible at worst. Did you realise the role is copying the *.rules files from your controller to the right folder in Prometheus for you already? (But it must have a .rules extension). Ref: https://prometheus-community.github.io/ansible/branch/main/prometheus_role.html#parameter-main--prometheus_alert_rules_files and https://github.com/prometheus-community/ansible/blob/4e881c667d65eb0110b97c815aa9feb13a845f2f/roles/prometheus/tasks/configure.yml#L24

So, it there a real limitation for you to use the default .../rules/... location in your Prometheus instance? Given that, on your controller you can freely store them in .../rules.d/... since the role is going to ship them to the right place either way.


I created a playbook - playbook.yaml, with the following content:

If this is the exact content of your playbook, your variables are ignored because you passed them outside of the vars keyword (please check Using roles at the play level for details). It should have been something like this:
---
- hosts: prometheus-server
  become: true
  roles:
    - role: prometheus.prometheus.prometheus
      vars:
        prometheus_version: "2.43.0"  
        prometheus_config_dir: "/sites/prometheus"
        prometheus_web_listen_address: "0.0.0.0:9090"  
        prometheus_global: {"evaluation_interval": "1m5s", "scrape_interval": "1m", "scrape_timeout": "59s"}
        prometheus_external_labels: {"environment": "env1"}
        prometheus_alert_rules_files: ["/sites/prometheus/rules.d/rules.yml"]
        prometheus_alertmanager_config: 
          - scheme: http
            static_configs:
              - targets:
                - alertmanager-1.xxx:9093

Alternatively, and I would call it a preferable way as it's more flexible and doesn't require playbook changes, you could put the variables directly into your inventory:
---
all:
  hosts:
    prometheus-server:
      ansible_host: x.x.x.x  
  vars:
    ansible_user: ubuntu
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/id_rsa_test
    ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa myuser@server.x"'
    prometheus_version: "2.43.0"  
    prometheus_config_dir: "/sites/prometheus"
    prometheus_web_listen_address: "0.0.0.0:9090"  
    prometheus_global: {"evaluation_interval": "1m5s", "scrape_interval": "1m", "scrape_timeout": "59s"}
    prometheus_external_labels: {"environment": "env1"}
    prometheus_alert_rules_files: ["/sites/prometheus/rules.d/rules.yml"]
    prometheus_alertmanager_config: 
      - scheme: http
        static_configs:
          - targets:
            - alertmanager-1.xxx:9093


The problem was finally related to using prometheus.prometheus.prometheus, and because the playbook was inside of the role, causing some problems while executing.
By changing the route of the playbook, and using only "prometheus" as role, this was solved.

How could a playbook be inside of the role? Playbooks and tasks have different syntax.
